# How to give folder path in require in express js

Tags: node.js, express, meanjs

My project skeleton,

```
 -app
   |_modules

   |_test
          |_test.js
```

my test.js

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('../modules');
var should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

error

```
Error: Cannot find module '../modules'
```

Can some one please help me........Thanks.

Comment: what is `_modules` ? I don't think it is a file

Comment: i changed name modules to server it worked

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `require` an entire folder, but a specific file, such as:

```
var server = require('../_modules/server.js');
```

Mind you, the module you're requiring should have defined exports. For further detail, I recommend reading the official documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html.